# Room automatically sorts primary key in Android

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I have a data class like this

```
public class WeekModel {
@PrimaryKey
@SerializedName("Id")
@Expose
private int id;
@SerializedName("Name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("StartDate")
@Expose
private String startDate;
@SerializedName("EndDate")
@Expose
private String endDate;}
```

Then in DAO I have saving and getting methods like this

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM WeekModel")
Single<List<WeekModel>> GetAllWeeks();

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void InsertAllWeeks(List<WeekModel>weeks);
```

i am saving a list of **Weeks** and then later on retrieving them. So whenever I retrieve them I get the list sorted according to the id which is the primary key.
But I don't need a sorted list like that, I need to get the data as it was saved in the database. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: question updated

Comment: Try with SELECT * FROM WeekModel ORDER BY StartDate

Comment: startDate is a string

Comment: `CAST()` it to a Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create another field called timestamp

```
private long timeStamp;
```

When you save data to room set the time of data saved

```
weekModel.setTimeStamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

then Call your query like this

```
SELECT * FROM WeekModel ORDER BY timeStamp asc
```

You will get the data as it was saved in the database

Comment: i receive the data sorted from backend already.. i want to save it as received

Comment: You are receiving from the DB it in order of primary key, this is normal.

Comment: @Ahmedsenosy It is possible, If you directly show data to users from internet without using room. but you are using room. Room provides an abstraction layer over SQLite .  SQLite saves and fetch without an order or whatever it likes, see [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6053/175139)